# gstreamer hangs when encoding a splitted stream with h264

Tags: gstreamer, h.264

I am using gstreamer to build a pipeline which splits an incoming video stream into two branches, one of which is displayed on the screen, and the other one is encoded and saved on the disk. However, the pipeline hangs after a few frames, and I fail to understand why. To reproduce the issue, just run the following

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! autovideosink t.! queue ! x264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=sample.mkv`

I found something that might be relevant here
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/x264/index.html?gi-language=c

In particular

> Some settings, including the default settings, may lead to quite some latency (i.e. frame buffering) in the encoder. This may cause problems with pipeline stalling in non-trivial pipelines, because the encoder latency is often considerably higher than the default size of a simple queue element. Such problems are caused by one of the queues in the other non-x264enc streams/branches filling up and blocking upstream. They can be fixed by relaxing the default time/size/buffer limits on the queue elements in the non-x264 branches, or using a (single) multiqueue element for all branches. Also see the last example below. You can also work around this problem by setting the tune=zerolatency property, but this will affect overall encoding quality so may not be appropriate for your use case.

However, I still do not understand how a queue put on a different branch can affect what x264enc is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Understand what PREROLLING in GStreamer means. (TL;DR, the pipeline will wait for each sink to have at least one buffer ready before it can switch to PLAYING)

Also keep in mind that data buffers are passed around via reference, not copies. Now think about what happens with lookahead in the encoder (TL;DR, it will consume frames without outputting enything, until enough lookahead frames have entered the encoder. The diplay brnach howver will not consume anything)

If the display sink does not consume anything it will block upstream, because where would the data go elsewhere. If upstream is blocked, it cannot deliver anymore data to the encoder which it requires to unblock itself. Hence everything stalls.

Comment: Thank you! So the prerolling phase lasts until all the components (x264enc included) have written something in the output buffers.
x264enc does not output anything until a given number of frames have been read, but continues consuming frames from his queue.
On the other hand, the autovideosink only consumes 1 frame during prerolling, and then stops, so his queue fills up. When the queue is full, the queue stops the videotestsrc, which however did not produce enough frames for the encoder to finish the prerolling phase.
Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: That's correct. And if you make the queue big enough (or reduce the latency of x264enc to fit into the queue) there will be no issue.

Comment: That's great, thank you!